# cargo-sbf fails on Quickstart guide

Tags: solana-program

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/farms/docs/quick_start.md

When running `cargo build-sbf` in any of the program folders, my build fails due to `termcolor` package

```
cargo build-sbf
   Compiling libc v0.2.132
   Compiling termcolor v1.1.3
   Compiling atty v0.2.14
   Compiling arrayvec v0.7.2
error[E0425]: cannot find function `is` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:98:6
   |
98 |     !is(stream)
   |      ^^ not found in this scope

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `atty` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0107]: this struct takes 0 lifetime arguments but 1 lifetime argument was supplied
   --> src/lib.rs:375:20
    |
375 |     StdoutLock(io::StdoutLock<'a>),
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^---- help: remove these generics
    |                    |
    |                    expected 0 lifetime arguments

error[E0107]: this struct takes 0 lifetime arguments but 1 lifetime argument was supplied
   --> src/lib.rs:376:20
    |
376 |     StderrLock(io::StderrLock<'a>),
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^---- help: remove these generics
    |                    |
    |                    expected 0 lifetime arguments

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0107`.
error: could not compile `termcolor` due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've actually found a bug in the docs, thanks for that!  The solution is to use `cargo build-bpf` everywhere.

The farms code is a bit out of date, so it depends on older crates that haven't updated to the correct `target_os = "solana"` build feature, so it must still be built with the `bpf` architecture.

The PR to fix is at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/3612

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure most of the docs/readme are wrong for the fund :/

Comment: Contributions in the form of issues or PRs are always appreciated!